# Notation/terminology for "independent" subspaces/subalgebras

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, notation, terminology

Let $V$ denote a vector space (or any other kind of algebraic structure).

> **Question.** Letting $I$ denote a fixed set and $X$ denote an $I$-indexed family of subspaces (subalgebras) of $V$, is there better
>   notation than $\bigoplus_{i:I} X_i = \sum_{i:I}X_i$ and/or
>   $\bigsqcup_{i:I} X_i = \bigvee_{i:I}X_i$ to mean that the projection
>   $\bigsqcup_{i:I} X_i \twoheadrightarrow \bigvee_{i:I}X_i$ is injective?
>
> Also: is there accepted terminology for this condition?

For example, if $A$ denotes an $n \times n$ real matrix and $X : \mathrm{Eigenvalue}(A) \rightarrow \mathrm{Subspace}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the corresponding eigenspace function, then I'd like to be able to say: "$X$ satisfies [whatever]."

Comment: For Question 0, aren't these both equivalent to $X \cap Y = \{0\}$?  That's probably the best way to write it.

Comment: For Question 0 I would say "disjoint" in the case of vector spaces (or any other context where the condition is equivalent to $X\cap Y$ being trivial in some obvious sense).  Question 1 is an interesting one though; I don't recall ever hearing a term for that.  If I needed a term, I would probably say "(linearly) independent", but I wouldn't use such a term without providing a definition unless it was very clear from context.

Comment: Accepted terminology: "internal direct sum" (this is standard terminology) and "internal disjoint union" (this is analogous wording that you'll have to define before using).

Comment: @darijgrinberg, as in "$X$ is an internal direct sum"?

Comment: As in "$\bigoplus_{i \in I} X_i$ (internal direct sum)".

Comment: @darijgrinberg, $X$ is a function, not a subspace. I don't like that way of talking.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your notation. Comment edited.

Comment: @darijgrinberg, I'm not sure that's really a solution. Writing $\bigoplus_{i:I} X_i$ somewhere in your notation as a way of telling your reader implicitly that a certain function happens to be injective is just asking for trouble. I'm hoping for a solution more along the lines of "$X$ is [something]."

Comment: Then "linearly disjoint" or "linearly independent" is your best bet, but do define the notation.

Comment: @darijgrinberg, "linearly disjoint" is a nice suggestion. You should consider posting that as an answer.

Comment: Actually, no, sorry, it is no nice suggestion. I've just googled the word and I found it has a more standard meaning which is rather different ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearly_disjoint ). So "linearly independent" is the better option among the two. Whatever you use, do define the notation -- there are no good standards here.